# YUI.getElementsBy equivalent to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

Is there any JQuery method/implementation that equivalent to YUI.getElementsBy?

YUI.getElementsBy ( method , tag , root , apply , o , overrides )

thanks,
Simon

Comment: Go nuts: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of that method is as follows:

> `Array getElementsBy ( method , tag , root , apply , o , overrides )`
>
> Returns an array of HTMLElements that pass the test applied by
>   supplied boolean method

You can replicate that functionality in jQuery with the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, and if you want to return an array of HTMLElement objects, you can use [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (otherwise you will have a jQuery object):

```
$(selector).filter(method).get();
```

In the jQuery version, both `tag` and `root` arguments would be combined into the selector.