# Jquery version of yui .getElementsBy

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I am trying to update from YUI to jQuery for a web app; however, I am new to working in jQuery. I have this code block in YUI:

```
function getChildUL(childEl){
    var childrenUL = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsBy(
        function(element) { 
            return element.parentNode == childEl; 
        }, "UL", childEl);
    childrenUL = childrenUL[childrenUL.length-1];

    return childrenUL;
}
```

I had found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428409/yui-getelementsby-equivalent-to-jquery), and tried rewriting the block in jQuery based on the accepted answer. I am getting undefined for childrenUL. This is my attempt:

```
function getChildUL(childEl){
    var childrenUL = $("UL").filter(function(element) { 
        return element.parentNode == childEl; 
    }).get();
    childrenUL = childrenUL[childrenUL.length-1];

    return childrenUL;
}
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code: parentNode isn't a jQuery function. I think you should use **parent()** or **closest()** function.